# How to enable interactive mode of apt install?

Tags: apt

I wanted `apt install` to prompt me `Do you want to continue`, but it didn't, while `apt remove` did. Maybe it was because I excuted some scripts, but I don't know which. I looked through `man apt-get` and googled with no anwsers. Most of questions are related with `disable interfactive mode`. So how could I get the prompts back?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What was the exact command you were running and what was its full output? `apt` does not ask if it is going to do what you requested _only_. If it’s going to install/remove more packages than you requested, then it asks.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164464/force-apt-get-to-prompt-yes-no

Comment: @Melebius It is just as you said. I'm an idiot. I thought it always asks.

Comment: @NGRhodes Thanks.

Comment: @Macondo Don’t be worried, I also used to think it asks always. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt` does not ask if it is going to do what you requested *only*. If it’s going to install/remove more packages than you requested, then it asks.